# VB script runs perfectly manually but fails to update the excel files through scheduled task manager

Tags: excel, vbscript, add-in, taskmanager

The problem is that VB script runs perfectly manually but fails to "update" the excel files through scheduled task manager. The update of the excel files are performed by using add-in.
Could you have any ideas why this happens? What are the differences when it is run manually or by task manager? 
(all rights are given)

Comment: Add some debugging code to your script to log step-by-step what the script is doing. I recommend [logging to eventlog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4ce6by3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), because that way file system permissions won't get in the way. For further analysis you need to show your script and the settings of the scheduled task.

Comment: log-files show the success

Comment: Then what isn't working? Please describe the problem in more detail. We're not sitting in front of your computer, so we cannot see what's going on.

Comment: Dear Ansgar, thank you for your assistance. Indeed, more details are needed. The scheduled task manager each morning runs the vbs files, which should open excel files, refresh the workbooks, save the excel files, close them. Excel files have add-inns, which should also perform some tasks when the excel files are open. The final result is a new excel file which is created with new information.

The point is that, when vbs files are run manually, everything updated properly. But when these vbs files are run by scheduled task manager there is no update.

Comment: Maybe add-inns are not open when the excel files run automatically.. Do you know how it is possible to verify?

Comment: A description of what your code is supposed to do is not sufficient for troubleshooting your problem. Please show your code as well as the settings of your scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that macros are available by default ? 
maybee it happens because when its run from the task manager it runs without macros enable.

first make sure that macros are available

Comment: Yes, the macros are enabled by vbscript